# Hide/replace certain source and destination IP in Wireshark packet table

Tags: wireshark

For demonstration purposes I need to show Wireshark packet table, but I need to hide some of the IP's there, like show `10.0.0.1` instead of `192.168.1.19`. Very old threads suggest using Linux-only tools (I am on Windows) or text search&replace, but I thought a similar feature should be part of Wireshark by now.

Is there a way to hide/replace/fake certain IP address in source/destination column preferable with some Wireshark tools? This is not required to be done at capture time, altering recorded session or .pcap file will also work.

Comment: if you want to modify the existing pcap file I recommend you tcpreplay tools (https://tcpreplay.appneta.com/)